# What's the difference between ActiveDataProvider and SQLDataProvider?

Tags: yii2

I'm a little bit confused. I'm wondering what is the difference between Yii2 `ActiveDataProvider` and `SQLDataProvider`? I was looking in the documentation for it, but couldn't get it too.

Could someone explain me when should I use one or another? And what is the difference between it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlDataProvider` works with a raw SQL statement which is used to fetch the needed data and `ActiveDataProvider` can take either a `yii\db\Query` or `yii\db\ActiveQuery` **object**.

`SqlDataProvider` example:

```
$provider = new SqlDataProvider([
   'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE status=:status',   //HERE
   'params' => [':status' => 1],
   'totalCount' => $count,
   'pagination' => [
       'pageSize' => 10,
   ],
   'sort' => [
       'attributes' => [
           'title',
           'view_count',
           'created_at',
       ],
   ],
]);
```

---

`ActiveDataProvider` example:

```
$query = Post::find()->where(['status' => 1]);     // ActiveQuery here

$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,                // and here
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'created_at' => SORT_DESC,
            'title' => SORT_ASC, 
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Could you tell me a situation when we need to use that `SqlDataProvider`? Why would we need to write a raw SQL statement when we can write a `query` (as in your second example)?

Comment: `SqlDataProvider` can be used when you have **really really** complex SQL query, it's often used by begginers when they don't know how to convert query to `ActiveQuery`.